# Is it possible to know the name of controller which responsible for some HTML fragment from browser?

Tags: angularjs

i'm beginning angular developer and i have application with some controllers.

Is it possible to find out what is the Name the controller of some html if there is no "ng-controller" statement?
Like in case this is custom directive or the html loaded by ui-router?

p.s. i know about batarang but i dont see the name of the controller, only the scope

Thanks

Comment: The controllers do not necessarily need to have a name. One can attach arbitrary functions as controllers to `ng-view` via `routeProvider`. Is there anything specific you want to do with the controller name once you have it or do you want to use it for debugging purposes?

Comment: thanks for answer, yes i need it for debugging purposes.But like you said it - controller may have no name (unless it specified as some scope value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can get hold of the DOM element you are interested in, you can run in the console:

```
angular.element(...).controller().constructor
```

This will print the constructor function (i.e. the function you have registered as controller) in the console; clicking on it (at least on Firebug) gets you to the source.

`.controller()` is an addon to the jQuery API from Angular. To get hold of the element in interest, the simplest thing is `document.getElementById()`. You can even use Firebug (or equivalent) to place an id in that element and then use `getElementById()`.

Also for Firefox/Firebug let me propose the excellent [angscope](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/angscope-simple-angularjs-s/) plugin.

Comment: thank you! that  exactly the thing i wanted:
 angular.element($0).controller().constructor